# Why does an arrow make a duplicate component in a PlantUML diagram?

Tags: plantuml

I'm very new to PlantUML, so this is likely something basic.

Sometimes when I add a arrow from one rectangle to another, the original component is not linked.  Instead, a new component is created and linked.  What am I doing wrong?

In my [example](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ROyn3u9038Nt-nKljpFew63G61C65uaJOQXSDIOSa5un4iD_5s4XujZtldvfuw0aslhIE5AwKc3OmzxYRO2Ra6USsvB3E0F2XL9rBmSeKVPOsR_n-XltfZTcrkoQ1YdBasMopwfJXqjYV_Yq2yf-mHxhUYIpSIb756sHJSVasA0G9cLGvS3keIQRD0kENofKg8cvSiFt7m00), I have this fairly simple diagram:

```
@startuml
database "DB" {
  frame Rules {
    rectangle "Item 1"
    rectangle "Item 2"
  }
}

rectangle "App Server" {
  rectangle "My UI"
}

rectangle "System" {
  rectangle "Foo"
}

[My UI] --> [Item 1] : create and edit
[System] --> [Item 1] : extract
@enduml
```

And this is generated:

[image: Resulting image]

Note that the arrow from System to Item 1 is for a new component and not the existing "System" element.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the [same question](https://forum.plantuml.net/13272/why-does-an-arrow-make-a-duplicate-component) in the PlantUML forum, and was told that this is due to the brackets around the name `System` in the arrows.  I guess they can only be used if the name contains a space.

So replacing

```
[System] --> [Item 1] : extract
```

with

```
System --> [Item 1] : extract
```

[fixes the issue](http://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/uml/ROyn3u9038Nt-nKljpFew63G61C65uaJOQXSDIOSa5un4iD_5s4XwDZtldvfuw0aslhIE5AwKc3OmzxYRO2Ra6USsvB3E0F2XL9rBmSeKVPOsR_n-XltfZTcrkoQ1YdBasMopwfJXqjY5tpQ1MN_mnxhUYIpSIb756sHJSVasA0G9cLGvS3keMQoB2b-gL2X9kRA3Rz_0000), and creates this diagram:

[image]

Comment: "they can only be used if the name contains a space." -- if that were true, changing the name to "System 1" and [System 1] would fix the problem, too, but it doesn't. My theory is that an aggregate (e.g., `rectangle System { ... }`) is different than an atomic element (e.g., `rectangle "My UI"`). The latter can be referenced with brackets whereas the former can't. Either way, it's not obvious!

Comment: Hmm, you may be right.  I haven't really thought about this since.